# Spring - Stop a background task running on port 8080

Tags: spring, windows, cmd, port

I was working in a Spring boot application and for some reason my Intellij get blocked so i force it to restart. the problem is when i try to start the embedded tomcat server in Spring i get:

```
Description:

Web server failed to start. Port 8080 was already in use.

Action:

Identify and stop the process that's listening on port 8080 or configure this application to listen on another port.
```

So i look how to stop it and i find this method to stop it:

- run this command in `cmd` with administrative privileges.

```
netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT>
```

and i get:

[image]

And get the PID to run `taskkill`:

```
taskkill /PID <PID> /F
```

but i get this:

[image]

so i try to run it with the `/T` parameter to kill all child process, but i get the same error:

[image]

i look into task manager and indeed, don´t find a `PID` with that code:

[image]

I didn´t find other method to work and i get stuck with that port, i know i can change the port to be used by Spring but i just wanna know if i can free that port, i also try turn off my pc and didn't work. Also i looked for `localhost:8080` in my browser and it just stays charging indefinitely.

- I run this command to see the process running on that port and is `java.exe` so i try to kill that task but doesn't work:

```
tasklist /SVC /FI "PID eq 16068
```

[image]

Try to kill that task with this command `taskkill /IM java.exe /F /T`, but i get `ERROR: The process "java.exe" with PID 16068 could not be terminated. Reason: There is no running instance of the task.`

[image]

Also i try end the task with the task manager but says `Access is denied`

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Use this command `taskkill /PID <PID> /T /F` -> /T kills child process

Comment: Doesn't work, says that ```There is no running instance of the task.```

Comment: oh okay, then maybe try just this ->
taskkill /PID <PID>

Comment: Doesn't work, says that ```ERROR: The process with PID 16068 could not be terminated.
Reason: This process can only be terminated forcefully (with /F option).``` and when i do it with ```/F``` option says: ```ERROR: The process with PID 16068 could not be terminated.
Reason: There is no running instance of the task.```